# How To Scan Barcode using Zxing Library in my android App

Tags: android, zxing

I am developing an application related to Barcode scanning. When I am going to scan the barcode, some barcodes are getting result while some barcodes are not able to be scanned.

My code is as below

```
cam_scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,UPC_E,ITF,RSS_14");
            intent.putExtra("SAVE_HISTORY", false);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            System.out.println(contents + "/n" + format);
            BarcodeId.setText(contents);

            ScannedBarcode();

            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE,ITF,RSS14");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

From the above code, I am not able to scan all the barcodes, I added user permissions, Included zxing lib android libraries.

In onActivityResult function, I am again opening camera scan to scan multiple barcodes one by one.

By referring tutorials I got to know that zxing libs mainly supports for scanning QR Codes only rather than barcodes. Is that right ? .

Can you please have a look into my issue and help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you starting the scanner again after a successful scan ? Which type of barcodes are not working ? Have you tired to use their  official application (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) to see if you can scan the barcode from there ?

Comment: In onActivityResult function, I am again opening camera scan to scan multiple barcodes one by one.

Comment: I am scanning Code_39 type barcodes creating in web application

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to scan the barcode with the BarcodeScanner app ? If that is working then something is wrong with the Intent you build to launch the scanner app.

Also I would suggest to change the request code from 0 to some random positive number. Maybe that's why you don't get any result.